# Book read in the late 1980s, early 1990s (pulp paperback)?

Tags: story-identification

I read this sometime after 1989 in paperback. It weighed in at less than 400 pages with certainty. My memory of the plot is vague, but it concerns a rural Alaskan village or town which is "snowed in". (Thinking about it, it might also be Canada, though that seems doubtful to me.) Something sinister is going on, which culminates in a small army of once-human monsters to trek in (I think they may be acclimated to the cold or immune to it).

There is something strange about the footprints they leave in the snow as well.

I also suspect this might be from the same author as *Tomb Seven* (Gene Snyder). He does not have a Wikipedia page or online bibliography that I can find (Goodreads looks incomplete at best).

This book isn't a good book and I don't recommend it, assuming anyone can identify it.

Comment: Did you try [ISFDb](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?2649)?

Comment: @DavidW I don't believe that to be complete either. Or it's just a false lead. Lord knows this other book is as bad as Tomb Seven (which reads like a made-for-tv movie script that was rejected, complete with the climax that doesn't settle anything).

Comment: Just to be clear, does the book follow the town dealing with the monsters, or people coming in from the outside to find the aftermath?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots The town doesn't survive it. If that sounds like 30 Days of Night, I suppose it is a little, but really poorly. I don't believe there's anyone coming in to find the aftermath at the end, but if there is he at least keeps it to a single short chapter.

Comment: gloomy read....

Comment: @GwenKillerby Might have been gloomy, by a better author. I thought it goofy even then, but at the time wouldn't have been able to go to the bookstore for a replacement til the weekend. And if I'm 50 pages in, I usually felt obligated to finish it. But something made me think of it the other day, and now I want to know what it was that I read.

Comment: fantasticfiction.com have a list of his books.

Comment: @JohnO Now *I* want to read it too! Damn you for making me curious!  ;-)  ;-)  ;-)  ;-)  ;-) j/k!